# Exporting layout file from ArcGIS Pro project to *.pagx file using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, export, arcgis-pro, layouts

I'm trying to implement a tool to import *.pagx files exported from ArcGIS Pro  to a  project, modify text elements and export the altered layouts back to the *.pagx files. It is pretty easy to export these files via [ArcGIS Pro GUI,](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/overview/save-a-layout-file.htm) but I'm struggling to find a way to export these files via *ArcPy*.

So far I used the following code to modify layout from the individual *.pagx file:

```
import arcpy

layout = arcpy.mp.ConvertLayoutFileToLayout(r"C:\temp\templates\8x11 Landscape.pagx")
for element in layout.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT'):
    if element.name == 'Text 4':
        element.text = "New text"
```

but there is no way to save the modified `layout` object as a file.
Also I tried to loop through the layouts, imported to the Pro project

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\username\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Layouts\Layouts.aprx")

for layout in aprx.listLayouts():
    for element in layout.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT'):
        if element.name == 'Text 4':
            element.text = "New text"
aprx.save()
```

Using the save() method I can save the project, but again there is no way to export the *.pagx files. I heard somewhere that I could export these *.pagx files via the .Net API only, but I'm still not 100% sure if such export feature is not implemented in ArcPy, or I overlooked something.

---

I tried to employ jsontocim module, located in "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\cim\cimloader\jsontocim.py"

```
from arcpy.mp import ConvertLayoutFileToLayout 
from arcpy.cim.cimloader.cimtojson import CimJsonEncoder
from json import dumps
layout = ConvertLayoutFileToLayout(r"C:\temp\templates\8x11 Landscape.pagx")
cim = layout.getDefinition('V2')
outJSON = dumps(cim, cls=CimJsonEncoder, indent=2)
print(outJSON)
```

It produced the output, resembling the structure of the *.pagx file, exported via GUI ,but some parts are missing or their structure differs from the original file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the [enhancement requested by @KHimba](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/334069/115) has been implemented because the latest help (for ArcGIS Pro 2.7.2) for the [Layout class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) includes an `exportToPAGX` method that:

> Exports a layout to a page file.

> ...

> This method is useful if you want to save a layout to a page file that can be imported later into a project using the ArcGISProject importDocument method.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, there is no out of the box function to do this.
I actually submitted this as an enhancement request a few months ago. It's currently "in product plan", meaning that Esri plans on doing it. As of writing (2.4.1), it has *not* been implemented.

Tracking reference:

> ENH-000119472 The ability to export the layout in ArcGIS Pro to a .pagx file through Python